# extract, match and combine information from string into array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Problem**

(*sorry, had problems, cutting it into smaller pieces*):

I have the following one column table `A`

```
                    s                            
-------------------------------------------
 (AAB) Some name1 1234 (XY*) Hello world 12
 (BB) Just one 123
```

and a lookup table `L`

```
 a1  | a2  
-----+-----
 XY* | XY
 AAB | A2B
```

I want to :

1. retrieve the parts in the brackets: `(AAB, XY*)`
2. get the corresponding `a2` entry from the lookup table: `(A2B, XY)`
3. retrieve the number part of the entries: `(1234, 12)`
4. combine the results from 2 and 4 into an array: `(A2B1234, XY12)`

The results would be

```
                    s                            
-------------------------------------------
 {A2B1234, XY12}
 {BB123}
```

---

**What I tried**

This is how far I got:

- For 1:

  `SELECT array_to_string(regexp_matches(s, '\((.*?)\)', 'g'), '') as in_bracket 
  FROM A;`
- For 3:

  `SELECT array_to_string(regexp_matches(s, '(\d+)', 'g'), '') as numbers
  FROM A;`

Here the struggle begins. How can I

1. Replace the values (`in_bracket`) with the lookup values on the fly?
2. Combine the results from the two select clauses into one array per row?

---

**The data:**

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  s VARCHAR
);
INSERT INTO a VALUES
  ('(AAB) Some name1 1234 (BB) More text 99 (XY*) Hello world 12'),
  ('(BB) Just one 123');

CREATE TABLE L (
  a1 VARCHAR(4),
  a2 VARCHAR(4)
);
INSERT INTO L VALUES 
  ('XY*', 'XY'),
  ('AAB', 'A2B');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to this form:

```
WITH parts AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        (regexp_matches(s, '\(([^\)]+)\)[^0-9]*([0-9]+)', 'g'))[1] AS search,
        (regexp_matches(s, '\(([^\)]+)\)[^0-9]*([0-9]+)', 'g'))[2] AS number
    FROM
        A
)
SELECT
    array_agg(L.a2 || parts.number)
FROM
    parts
    JOIN L
    ON (L.a1 = parts.search)
GROUP BY
    parts.id;
```

The output is:

```
{A2B1,XY12}
{BB123}
```

There are some thing that needs to be clarified:

- what exactly is "number part of the entries" - in given example there is "name1", so my regex matches the "1" - note that `A2B1` is returned instead of `A2B1234`
- in table `L` there is no entry for `BB` - I have added it manually to my test `L` table - should just text in brackets be used in such situation?
- I needed to group result from table `A`, and I have assumed that there is `id` column - you can also use `s` column for that provided that it is quniue

You may need to adjust the regex I've used. Here is an explanation to my version:

```
\(         - '('
([^\)]+)   - match of sequence of any char except ')' - this will be for example `AAB` or `XY*`
\)         - ')'
[^0-9]*    - any sequence of chars except digits (no-matching group)
([0-9]+)   - match of non-empty sequence of digits
```

Comment: SQL power in action! :) This seems to work perfectly. In my scenario it may happen, that there is no corresponding value in the lookup table. But a simple left join will take care of this and only return the values I need to extract. Thanks a ton!